# Remove <BR> from tag jquery live (OpenCart)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code.
But when i add product to cart, this code not working. (OpenCart)
How to make the worker live? 
Thanks!

This my html:

```
<span id="cart-total">1 item(s) $589.50</span>
```

but after add to cart

```
<span id="cart-total">1 item(s) <br> $589.50</span>
```

how i can delete forever BR?

i have script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cart-total br').remove();
});
```

Comment: please show your html

Comment: this will only work when your document is ready. please share more code or create a fiddle...

Comment: please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work only for the first time when the document is ready.
If you want to make it live add this code in your script after every add to cart.

```
 $('#cart-total br').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why adding product to cart will add

```
<br>
```

in your html code is more important to find.

Or you can just use you code on you addToCart function's bottom to remove it every time you call the function.

```
function addToCart() {
   // your code
   // here
   // ....

   $('#cart-total br').remove();
}
```